# Constructing a field with exactly $81$ elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, ideals

I was thinking $\frac{\mathbb{Z_3}[x]}{(x^3+x+1)} \times \frac{\mathbb{Z_3}[x]}{(x^3+x+1)}$.

$(x^3+x+1)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z_3[x]}$ so the quotient will be a field, and a field cross a field looks like it should be a field to me!

How would I do this if working over $\mathbb{Z_9}$ and $\mathbb{Z_2}$? in $\mathbb{Z_9}$ i would have to find an irreducible quadratic, and then quotient out by that, correct? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: A "field cross a field" is not a field. It can have zero divisors.

Comment: That can’t be a field: a direct product of two rings always has zero divisors: $(a,0)*(0,a)  = (0,0)$, even when $a\neq 0$. And you can’t do it working over $\mathbb{Z}_9$ either, because *that* has zero divisors.

Comment: Since $81 = 3^4$, try to find an irreducible polynomial of degree 4. Also, notice that $R\times S$ has $|R|*|S|$ elements; your cross product has $27\times 27 = 729$ elements, not 81.

Comment: Is there a process for finding an irreducible polynomial over a given modulus or do you just try things ?? Seems like it would be really tough to find an a degree 4 irreducible polynomial since checking for roots won't be enough

Comment: $\mathbb Z_9$ is not a field.

Comment: It’s not that tough for degree 4. If it has no roots but is reducible, then it is the product of two irreducible quadratics, which you may assume to be monic. $x^2+ax+b$ is irreducible quadratic over $\mathbb{Z}_3$ if and only if $a^2-4b\equiv 2\pmod{3}$.

Comment: Of course, this assumes that you actually have to exhibit the construction. If you have some theorems about splitting field under your belt, then there is a very easy way to “constructing” the field, by declaring it to be the splitting field of a particular polynomial.

Answer (score 3):

No you can't do $F \times F$ because $(a,0) \times (0,b) = (0,0)$ would break the field axioms.

You need to give an irreducible polynomial $P$ of degree $4$ over $\mathbb{Z}_3$ so you can give representatives of $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(P)$ by polynomials of degree $\leq 3$. The coefficients of $1$, $x$ $x^2$ and $x^3$ are free to choose so there are a total of $3^4$ elements of the field as desired.

Getting $P$ is more complicated. If you have a guess for an irreducible polynomial check it with [Rabin's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials_over_finite_fields#Rabin.27s_test_of_irreducibility)

Comment: Seems like it would be tough to find a degree 4 irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Z_3}$ because checking for roots won't be enough... got any tips?

Comment: @MichaelVaughan: Checking for roots isn’t enough; but then, if it is of degree $4$ and has no roots in $\mathbb{Z}_3$, then the only way it can fail to be irreducible is if it is the product of two irreducible quadratics. There aren’t that many irreducible quadratics, so you can check what all the products of two of them are.

Comment: The field extensions of degree 2, 3, 4, .. of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ have 8, 26, 80, ... non-zero elements, so the degree 4 extension is the smallest one with elements of order 5 and the polynomial $\frac{x^5-1}{x-1}=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ must work.

Answer (score 3):

A field with $81$ elements must be the splitting field of $x^{81}-x$. It is also an extension of $\mathbb F_3$ of degree $4$. Therefore, take any irreducible quartic factor of $x^{81}-x$, for instance, $x^4+x+2$. [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+x%5E81-x+mod+3) tells you all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see.  What are the irreducible quadratics:  $x^2+x+2\,,x^2+2x+2\,,x^2+1$.

I count $3$ (thanks @Lubin).

So, there are ${3\choose 2}+3=6$ combinations to check.

These are the $6$ quartics I get:  $x^4+1\,,x^4+x^3+x+1\,,x^4+2x^3+2x+2 \,,x^4+2x^3+x^2+x+1\,,x^4+x^3+x^2+2x+1\,,x^4+2x^2+1$.

But there are $2\cdot 3^4=162$ quartics to choose from... $81$ of them monic.

So, if I choose a quartic that doesn't have a root *and* isn't among the $6$ products, it will be irreducible.

So, how about $x^4+2x^3+2$?

Finally, $\mathbb F_{3^4}\cong\frac{\mathbb Z_3[X]}{x^4+2x^3+2}$.

Comment: Man, to me it seems like determining all the irreducible quadratics over $\mathbb{Z_3}$ would be tough, but you make it sound like it's so obvious. Did you just go through and check all of them to see which had roots? I guess that's not that bad

Comment: Yeah.  I was just about to list the $10 $ reducible ones...  Then we can choose one of the remaining $152$.

Comment: Wait.  I think I miscounted.   I included a lot of quartics that have a root.

Comment: But $2x^2+x+1=2(x^2+2x+2)$. Since there are only three pairs of conjugate points in $\Bbb F_9$, there are only three irreducible quadratics over $\Bbb F_3$. In fact, there are $81-9=72$ elements of $\Bbb F_{81}$ that generate over $\Bbb F_3$. These fall into $72/4=18$ quadruples of conjugate points. So there are $18$ irreducible quartics over $\Bbb F_3$. It shouldn’t be hard to find one of them.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to mess around with finding an irreducible quartic, you could construct $\mathbb{F}_{81}$ as the quotient of $\mathbb{F}_9[x]$ with a quadratic irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_9$. $\mathbb{F}_9$ can be constructed as the quotient of $\mathbb{F}_3[y]$ with a quadratic irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_3$, so you just have to find two different irreducible quadratics, which is easy since you just have to verify the quadratic has no roots in the field.

Expressing $\mathbb{F}_9\cong\mathbb{F}_3[y]/(y^2+1)$, one can check that $x^2+(y+1)$ has no roots in $\mathbb{F}_9$, so $\mathbb{F}_{81}\cong\mathbb{F}_9[x]/(x^2+y+1)$.